# Bulk Mail with different content

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I like to send bulk mail with different content, what is the best way to send.
Do I need to send one by one or there is any any best way.

```
Sample
EmailId:- sa@m.com
Body:- This mail for sa@m.com. Do you interview is schedule at 10:30 AM

EmailId:- sa1@m.com
Body:- This mail for sa1@m.com. Do you interview is schedule at 11:30 AM
```

Like above I have to send 1000 mails together.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it individually, i remember having to send 3 SMS messages to over 1000000 users - the DB couldnt cope as the DB design was bad, so it took 4 days, whereas after redesign it did them in 1 hour

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the right answer by [Theresa Forster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/621567/theresa-forster), as you send them individually, you may need to/want to schedule the sending. ESP's get curious on large volumes and have an automated red button to finger on, before the mailserver gets listed by Spamhaus or other lists - the worst scenario for an ESP. Hence, as this is of course not spam, send for example 30, wait 30 s, send 30, etc. A bit tighter schedule is probably possible,